# C# "Get" Not Working Correctly

Tags: c#, arrays, swap

I'm trying to make a swap operation. But when i tried to swap, it changes temp and the orginal array. The codes are here.

```
    private int[] currentNumbers;

    currentNumbers = new int[7] { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };

    public int[] getNumbers()
    {
        return currentNumbers;
    }

    int[] temp;
    int[] ux = numbers.getNumbers();

    int i=1, j=2;

    temp = swap(i, j, ux);

    public int[] swap(int i,int j,int[] u) {
        int t = u[i];
        u[i] = u[j];
        u[j] = t;
        return u;
    }
```

That code blocks changed ux array as planned. But changed currentNumbers. I don't want swap in orginal array. What can i do about that? Any ideas?

Comment: You need to copy the array.

Comment: "Correctly" and "how I wish it worked" aren't the same thing.

Comment: This title has no relation with the question being asked

Comment: Also you should look up reference and value types. :-)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1533757/is-int-a-reference-type-or-a-value-type

Comment: @SLaks "int[] ux = numbers.getNumbers();" already gets the array like copying. But there is no set method and i changed only ux array not currentNumbers.

Comment: @MügeKarakaş No, it doesn't, it returns a reference to the same array that `currentNumbers` is a reference to.

Comment: I've never seen such a thing before. Thanks for answering all guys.

Comment: @MügeKarakaş: Wrong.  C# never copies reference types for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expanding on what SLaks said, your .getNumbers() function isn't returning a copy of the array, it's returning a reference directly to currentNumbers. If you want to return a new copy every time and not modify currentNumbers, you should use Array.Copy.

```
int[] ux;
Array.Copy(numbers.getNumbers(), ux, numbers.getNumbers.Length)
```

There are probably more optimal ways to do this, but this will get you what you want!

Answer (score 1):

You should use clone method in getNumbers method.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.clone%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that arrays in c# are passed by reference, so you need to copy that array in another one, apply changes to that array, and then return it.

Check this answer for more details [Passing Arrays by Value and by Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10325323/passing-arrays-by-value-and-by-reference)

Comment: The array *reference* is passed *by value* - it's a minor distinction with different consequences. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8b0bdca4.aspx